# ValueError on list when using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, valueerror

I have a problem when processing a list of lists using a for loop that assigns list elements to variables instead of using list indexes.

The following code correctly processes the list and confirms that each sublist has 5 elements with all elements being of type string and all having data:

```
for i, rec in enumerate(Wordpress_Post_List): 
    if i < 5:
        if i == 0:
            print(type(rec), ' -->  ', len(rec))
        print('record ',i)
        print('0==', type(rec[0]), '==', rec[0])
        print('1==', type(rec[1]), '==', rec[1])
        print('2==', type(rec[2]), '==', rec[2])
        print('3==', type(rec[3]), '==', rec[3])
        print('4==', type(rec[4]), '==', rec[4])
```

But when I use the following code:

```
for i, rec in enumerate(Wordpress_Post_List): 
    if i < 5:
        for li0,li1,li2,li3,li4 in rec:
            print('0==', type(li0), '==', li0)
            print('1==', type(li1), '==', li1)
            print('2==', type(li2), '==', li2)
            print('3==', type(li3), '==', li3)
            print('4==', type(li4), '==', li4)
```

I get the error: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 2)

Any insights on why Python is doing this would be greatly appreciated.

PS. The following code also works.

```
for i, rec in enumerate(Wordpress_Post_List): 
    if i < 5:
        li0=rec[0]
        li1=rec[1]
        li2=rec[2]
        li3=rec[3]
        li4=rec[4]
        print('0==', type(li0), '==', li0)
        print('1==', type(li1), '==', li1)
        print('2==', type(li2), '==', li2)
        print('3==', type(li3), '==', li3)
        print('4==', type(li4), '==', li4)
```

Comment: Do include an example of the kind of values found in `Wordpress_Post_List` in your question, together with expected output.

Comment: In this specific case, we can make an educated guess as to what is going wrong, but having a good example of the kind of data the nested structure would let us be much, *much* more effective. And rather than just show the exception, the full traceback is usually also required so we can not only see what exception was thrown, but also how Python got there, and on what line *exactly* the problem occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over `rec`, and so each *individual value* in `rec` is assigned to the 5 variables. At least one of those values is itself a sequence (probably a string) and is only 2 elements long, and 2 elements can't be assigned to 5 variables.

E.g. if the first entry in `Wordpress_Post_List` is a list of 5 strings:

```
['on', 'a', 'distant', 'hazy', 'hill']
```

then a `for` loop takes `'on'` and will assign it to the `for` loop target. You set the target to `li0,li1,li2,li3,li4`, and because strings are sequences too, Python tries to assign the characters `'o'` and `'n'` to the 5 variable names. That can't work so you get your specific exception:

```
>>> rec = ['on', 'a', 'distant', 'hazy', 'hill']
>>> for li0,li1,li2,li3,li4 in rec:
...     pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 2)
```

Don't use another `for` loop, just use an *assignment* to those 5 names:

```
if i < 5:
    li0, li1, li2, li3, li4 = rec
```

Rather than use `enumerate()` and a test against `i`, you can use the [`itertools.islice()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) object to limit iteration to the first 5 rows. Because you know that the first five entries all have exactly 5 elements, you can then use unpacking in the outer loop:

```
from itertools import islice

for li0, li1, li2, li3, li4 in islice(Wordpress_Post_List, 5):
    print('0==', type(li0), '==', li0)
    print('1==', type(li1), '==', li1)
    print('2==', type(li2), '==', li2)
    print('3==', type(li3), '==', li3)
    print('4==', type(li4), '==', li4)
```

Comment: I believe that the source of my confusion here is that the code "for a,b,c in mainlist" works fine when mainlist contains more than one sublist but I see that it abends if mainlist only has 1 sublist within it.

Comment: Thanks Martijn for your help and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is attempting to unpack each iteration

`for (unpack,my,data,structure) in iterable_of_data_structures:`

`for li0,li1,li2,li3,li4 in rec:`

This requires that there be 5 values in each iteration of `rec`; however, we can see from your previous code that there are *5 values* in `rec`, total.

You could unpack without iteration:
`(li0, li1, li2, li3, li4) = rec`

Comment: Not quite right.  `rec` contains 5 values; if you iterate `rec`, you are iterating those 5 values, and then trying to unpack the value that your iterator is currently on into 5 variables with your `for li0,li1,li2,li3,li4 in rec:` line.

Comment: Replacing the code "for i, rec in enumerate(Wordpress_Post_List):" with the code "for i, (li0,li1,li2,li3,li4) in enumerate(Wordpress_Post_List):" does work. I was under the impression that I could use a for statement to put each element from the list into its own variable thus avoiding the use of indexes.  Still don't really understand why one form works and the other fails.

Comment: You want to perform two operations: the iterate operation, and the unpack operation.  You only want to iterate the `Wordpress_Post_list` structure, and you only want to unpack the `rec` structure.  When you do `for i, (li0,li1,li2,li3,li4) in enumerate(Wordpress_Post_List):` you iterate and unpack in one statement, and everything is fine.  When you do `for i, rec in enumerate(Wordpress_Post_List):` you iterate, and you can then unpack with something like `(li0, li1, li2, li3, li4) = rec`, and everything is fine.  Your problem code tried to iterate, *iterate*, and unpack: too many iterations.